# Association with proc for mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I saw in sources of Mongoid that no proc can be send to association method, what is best practice to achieve below AR association with Mongoid:

```
class Task
  ...

  belongs_to :creator, ->{where(type: :manager)}, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :acceptor, ->{where(type: :acceptor)}, class_name: "User"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I'm find answer. Relations methods in Mongoid accepts block as third argument.

```
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :created_tasks do
    ->{ where(type: :manager)}
  end

 belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :accepted_tasks do
   ->{where(type: :acceptor)}
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for has_many relations I've been having trouble getting this working with a default filter in mongo, so I wonder if your answer is actually working correctly for belongs_to. This has been working correctly on the has_many side for me so I figured it might be a useful answer for someone else as well:

```
 belongs_to :user do
   def creator
     where(type: :manager)}
   end

   def executor
     where(type: :acceptor)
   end
 end
```

They can then be accessed by saying `task.user.accepted`, `task.user.created`, etc, however I have been unable to figure out how to actually set the default filtering for the overall relation.